# Split a Column Based on first instance

Tags: python, split, series

Looking to split a df | series column into 2 parts based on the first "_"

example in column:

Male_85__and_over

```
test['gender'] = test['column_Name_pivoted'].str.split('_').str[0]
test['age'] = test['column_Name_pivoted'].str.split('_',n=1).str[1:]
```

Output is not what I was looking for:

| gender | age |
| --- | --- |
| Male | [85__and_over] |

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.extract` here:

```py
test[["gender", "age"]] = test.str.extract(r'([^_]+)_([^_]+)')
```

Comment: That splits at every level. so Male, 85.

Comment: Please elaborate on your comment.  AFAIK, my answer should be working with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
test[['gender','age']] =  test["column_Name_pivoted"].str.split("_", n=1, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.partition()`:

```
test['gender'], _, test['age'] = test['column_Name_pivoted'].str.partition("_")
```